# hibernatetool: java.util.zip.ZipException: error in opening zip file

Tags: eclipse, spring, hibernate, maven, ant

I am trying to run `build-sql` ant task which is giving me the following `[hibernatetool] java.util.zip.ZipException: error in opening zip file`. As it shows that this task does quite a lot which it actually does but it doesn't populate the database tables which it is supposed to. I think it is because of this error that I am getting. And as I read it somewhere that it might be because of having a `.properties` file inside `WEB-INF`, I do not have any `.properties` file inside `WEB-INF` of the project.

```
<target name="build-sql">
    <mkdir dir="target/sql"/>
    <artifact:pom id="myPom" file="pom.xml" />
    <artifact:dependencies filesetId="pomDeps" pomRefId="myPom" useScope="compile" />
    <property name="baseTarget" location="target/${myPom.build.finalName}/WEB-INF"/>
    <fileset id="libDir" dir="${baseTarget}/lib"/>
    <path id="build.runtime.classpath">
        <restrict>
            <difference>
                <fileset refid="pomDeps" />
                <intersect>
                    <fileset refid="pomDeps" />
                    <fileset refid="libDir" />
                </intersect>
            </difference>
            <rsel:not>
                <rsel:name name="**/*.pom" />
            </rsel:not>
        </restrict>
        <fileset refid="libDir"/>
    </path>
    <taskdef name="hibernatetool" classname="org.tbs.common.util.sql.HibernateToolTask" classpathref="build.runtime.classpath" />
    <hibernatetool destDir="target/sql" combinePersistenceUnits="false" refineFileNames="true">
        <classPathApplicationContext path="tbs-open-admin-contentClient-applicationContext.xml"/>
        <classPathApplicationContext path="tbs-cms-contentClient-applicationContext.xml"/>
        <classPathApplicationContext path="headmaster-applicationContext.xml"/>
        <jpaconfiguration persistenceUnit="tbsPU" dialect="org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect" />
        <jpaconfiguration persistenceUnit="tbsSecurePU" dialect="org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect" />
        <jpaconfiguration persistenceUnit="tbsCMSStorage" dialect="org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect" />
        <classpath refid="build.runtime.classpath" />
        <hbm2ddl export="false"/>
    </hibernatetool>
</target>
```

Following is the error part of logging:

```
[hibernatetool] java.util.zip.ZipException: error in opening zip file
[hibernatetool]     at java.util.zip.ZipFile.open(Native Method)
[hibernatetool]     at java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(ZipFile.java:114)
[hibernatetool]     at java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(ZipFile.java:131)
[hibernatetool]     at org.apache.tools.ant.AntClassLoader.getResourceURL(AntClassLoader.java:1028)
[hibernatetool]     at org.apache.tools.ant.AntClassLoader$ResourceEnumeration.findNextResource(AntClassLoader.java:147)
[hibernatetool]     at org.apache.tools.ant.AntClassLoader$ResourceEnumeration.<init>(AntClassLoader.java:109)
[hibernatetool]     at org.apache.tools.ant.AntClassLoader.findResources(AntClassLoader.java:975)
[hibernatetool]     at java.lang.ClassLoader.getResources(ClassLoader.java:996)
[hibernatetool]     at org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.singleImplementationSanityCheck(LoggerFactory.java:212)
[hibernatetool]     at org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.performInitialization(LoggerFactory.java:110)
[hibernatetool]     at org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.getILoggerFactory(LoggerFactory.java:268)
[hibernatetool]     at org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.getLogger(LoggerFactory.java:241)
[hibernatetool]     at org.apache.commons.logging.impl.SLF4JLogFactory.getInstance(SLF4JLogFactory.java:156)
[hibernatetool]     at org.apache.commons.logging.impl.SLF4JLogFactory.getInstance(SLF4JLogFactory.java:132)
[hibernatetool]     at org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory.getLog(LogFactory.java:351)
[hibernatetool]     at org.tbs.common.extensibility.context.StandardConfigLocations.<clinit>(StandardConfigLocations.java:29)
[hibernatetool]     at org.tbs.common.util.sql.HibernateToolTask.execute(HibernateToolTask.java:131)
[hibernatetool]     at org.apache.tools.ant.UnknownElement.execute(UnknownElement.java:288)
[hibernatetool]     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
[hibernatetool]     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
[hibernatetool]     at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
[hibernatetool]     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
[hibernatetool]     at org.apache.tools.ant.dispatch.DispatchUtils.execute(DispatchUtils.java:106)
[hibernatetool]     at org.apache.tools.ant.Task.perform(Task.java:348)
[hibernatetool]     at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.execute(Target.java:357)
[hibernatetool]     at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.performTasks(Target.java:385)
[hibernatetool]     at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeSortedTargets(Project.java:1337)
[hibernatetool]     at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeTarget(Project.java:1306)
[hibernatetool]     at org.apache.tools.ant.helper.DefaultExecutor.executeTargets(DefaultExecutor.java:41)
[hibernatetool]     at org.eclipse.ant.internal.launching.remote.EclipseDefaultExecutor.executeTargets(EclipseDefaultExecutor.java:32)
[hibernatetool]     at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeTargets(Project.java:1189)
[hibernatetool]     at org.eclipse.ant.internal.launching.remote.InternalAntRunner.run(InternalAntRunner.java:423)
[hibernatetool]     at org.eclipse.ant.internal.launching.remote.InternalAntRunner.main(InternalAntRunner.java:137)
```

I am just not able to understand the reason behind this.

Also, sometimes I get the following as well when I try to tun `mvn install` on my projects `pom.xml`. I am using Eclipse Java EE IDE Helios.

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:2.0.2:compile (default-compile) on project natura: Compilation failure
[ERROR] error: error reading C:\Users\lawson\.m2\repository\org\apache\xmlgraphics\batik-util\1.7\batik-util-1.7.jar; cannot read zip file entry
```

I am not sure if they are related but they seem to have driven me nuts already as I just can't figure out why am I getting those errors.

Could someone please help understand what am I missing here to resolve these problems.

Thanks.

Comment: What JRE version are you using ? I think I have seen this error before and I vaguely remember that it had something to do with a bug in the JRE (from Sun). I could be mixing things up though, my recollection of this error is vague but I know I've dealt with it before...

Comment: @Jasper: I am using `jdk1.6.0_17` and I have configured `-vm
C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.6.0_17\bin\javaw.exe` in eclipse.ini and have configured the Installed JREs and Execution environment in eclipse windows preferences pointing to `jdk1.6.0_17 ` folder on my system same as well.

Comment: Wow, thats quite a piece of antique ;-) Trying updating to the latest version of the 6 branch first. Java 6 Update 31.

Comment: @Jasper: I am right at it, will update you soon. Thanks.

Comment: @JasperSiepkes: I have changed the jdk version to 1.6.0_32 but I am still getting those errors. `[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:2.0.2:compile (default-compile) on project natura: Compilation failure
[ERROR] error: error reading C:\Users\lawson\.m2\repository\org\apache\xmlgraphics\batik-util\1.7\batik-util-1.7.jar; cannot read zip file entry` is not even letting me get to the point so that I could run the ant task.

Comment: Have you tried building your project with Maven from the command line (ie. outside of Eclipse) ? And what version of Maven are you using ?

Comment: @Jasper: I've the project built and installed this time. Don't quite know how and why did it happen but after restarting the computer and removing the old version of jdk and cleaning project it worked.

Comment: @Jasper: I am back to `[hibernatetool]: java.util.zip.ZipException: error in opening zip file` whn I run the ant task mentioned in the question.

Comment: @Jasper: I am using `apache-maven-3.0.3`.

Comment: @Jasper: I ran `mvn clean` on the projects pom and then again `mvn install` and this time again I got `[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:2.0.2:compile (default-compile) on project natura: Compilation failure
[ERROR] error: error reading C:\Users\lawson\.m2\repository\org\apache\xmlgraphics\batik-util\1.7\batik-util-1.7.jar; cannot read zip file entry`.

Comment: Delete the Batik directory 'C:\Users\lawson\.m2\repository\org\apache\xmlgraphics\batik-util\1.7\' from you local Maven Repo (cache) so that Maven downloads it again. It might have become corrupted. BTW you can also edit your comment if you need to add something.

Comment: @JasperSiepkes: I removed `batik-util` and could build the `mvn install` the project successfully.

Comment: @JasperSiepkes: It wasn't too long that the problem started happening again.

Answer (score 0):

Delete the folder in the repo and maven will download it again.

```
C:\Users\lawson\.m2\repository\org\apache\xmlgraphics\batik-util\
```